# camera has a sort of fisheye

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am toying around with p5js, and while generating some cubes, it appeared to me that the "camera" the "render" deforms around the edges, kind of like a fisheye to me.

[image: side to side cubes]

Here is the bit of code :

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 850, WEBGL);
    angleMode(DEGREES);
  }
  
  function draw() {
    //background color
    background("#ece5d8");

    //don't draw faces, only vertices
    noFill();
    //color of the strokes
    stroke(0);

    //save the following state
    push();
    //we save that we don't draw, that we face the edge, and that we're at the left

      //start drawing at the left
      translate(-200, 0, 0);

      //draw our cubes
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        push();
          translate(i * 150, 0, 0);
          box(150);
        pop();
      }
    pop();
  }
```

I only translate and never rotate or anything, why aren't the cube perfectly aligned with their edges, and why is it curving ?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you see the fish-eye effect? I tried importing your image into an image editor and the edges seem pixel-straight to me. It's not just an optical illusion?

Comment: Well, none of the cubes look like we're facing them, and the leftmost one has longer diagonals that the ones in the center

Comment: Yes of course, thats perspective projection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `WEBGL` mode the default camera projection is [perspective()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/perspective).
The edges don't curve like they would with fish-eye lens, they are straight, but the edge dimensions change based on depth.

If you want to render the cubes and have the edges simply use a parallel projection using [ortho()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/ortho):

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 850, WEBGL);
    ortho(-width / 2, width / 2, height / 2, -height / 2, -3000, 3000);
    angleMode(DEGREES);
  }
  
  function draw() {
    //background color
    background("#ece5d8");
    orbitControl();
    //don't draw faces, only vertices
    noFill();
    //color of the strokes
    stroke(0);

    //save the following state
    push();
    //we save that we don't draw, that we face the edge, and that we're at the left

      //start drawing at the left
      translate(-200, 0, 0);

      //draw our cubes
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        push();
          translate(i * 150, 0, 0);
          box(150);
        pop();
      }
    pop();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

**Note** Based on the dimensions and positioning of the boxes I've increased near/far clipping distances (last arguments of `ortho()`). I've also added `orthoControl()`: this is totally optional, but helpful to illustrate the ortho view (since by default a front view will look the same as using 2D `rect()` calls )